# Is there a Nuget package to configure a WCF application for Unity IOC?

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, nuget

There are a number of posts showing how to do it by hand -- which, incidentally, I've done before -- but I was surprised to find no Nuget package to add this functionality to your WCF project in a similar fashion to the way you can add Unity to an MVC3 project with *Unity.MVC3*.  I searched the online Nuget package source directory but came up with nothing.  If I missed something obvious, I'd appreciate it if you'd point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple of days ago [Paul Hiles](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-unity.wcf-providing-easy-ioc-integration-for-your-wcf-services) created the Unity.WCF NuGet package. I've verified it installs successfully. The source code is [on CodePlex](http://unitywcf.codeplex.com/). Thanks Paul!!